# iterate class object in arraylist in java

Tags: arraylist, iteration

i am adding class objects into my array list , now i have to iterate the objects in a loop and save into database

my bean class

```
 public class SchemeBean {

 private String code;
 private String name;
 private String value;

 public String getCode(){

 return code;

}

 public String getName(){

 return name;

 }


 public String getValue(){

 return value;

 }


  public SchemeBean(String code,String name,String value){

 this.code=code;
 this.name=name;
 this.value=value;


}
```

}

adding class objects in array

```
  ArrayList items= null ;
  String hd1 = jsonLineItem.getString("hd1");
  String hd2 = jsonLineItem.getString("hd2");
  String code = jsonLineItem.getString("code");
  items.add(new SchemeBean(code,hd1,hd2));
```

now i have this arraylist items which has got objects of SchemeBean added to it as its elements

now my requirement is that i have to iterate it and add it to database iam not understanding how to iterate it. please any hint would a greeat help for me

Answer (score 0):

```
for(SchemeBean item: items){
    System.out.println("item: "+item);
}
```

though you will need to Override `toString` method for proper output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<items.lenth-1; i++)
{
  Save(item[i]);
}
```

alternatively...

```
for (SchemeBean s : arrayList)
{
  Save(item[i]);
}
```

your save function skeleton ...

```
public void Save(SchemeBean s) 
{
  //Save the values to the db
}
```